# Mover columna hacia abajo con flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Tengo una caja con dos div.

```
<section class="general-info">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.general-info {
margin-top: 50px;
display: flex;
height: 250px;
width: 100%;
column-count: 2;
gap: 10px;
column-width: 300px;
}
```

Estoy usando flexbox, pero no se como hacer para que cuando el ancho de "image" llegue a un determinado tamaño, supongamos un "width:300px", se pongan uno sobre otro, como lo hace bootstrap.

Osea, que pasen de esto...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso es un diseño responsive. Es para el diseño en móviles, y se usa `@media`. O es que quieres en el mismo destock dependiendo del tamaño del  obtenido?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que siempre ocupe la mitad, osea que sean dos columnas, pero que cuando lleguen a cierto ancho, una se ponga sobre la otra. De todas formas lo resolvi usando `display:inline-block`